# Php, problems with method scoping (public for someone, private for others, C++ friend alike)

Tags: php, class

Two classes:

```
class main()
{
 public function doAjob()
 {
  helperClass::clean();
 }
}

class helperClass()
{
 public function add() { }
 public function remove() { }
 public function clean() { } // **this should be only allowed from main::doAjob() !!!**
}
```

the user of these classes are allowed to use doAjob(), add(), remove() methods, but not clean(). This is only allowed for main class. Its in kind of friend in C++. How to dodge it? The best would be not even seeing it by code competition.

Comment: Not possible, but you could make helperClass abstract, and then extend it with subclasses that make the methods public or private as you require. Not ideal, as you'll need to ensure your client classes use the correct class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in PHP. There is no concept of "friend" classes. If you want a method to be accessible outside the class, it must be `public`.

Answer (score 0):

well, there mightbe alternative those who reads this: make them public, and you can `backtrace()` function calls, and determine where did the call come from. This makes extremly slow the application though, so the best idea to add a mechanism to enable/disable.